# Multiple Documentation Windows Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone know how to open multiple documentation windows in Xcode? I feel like this is a silly question because something as basic as this should be included in Xcode, but I just can't seem to figure out how to enable this feature.

Thanks.

Comment: In Xcode 3, there was a right-click option to open a documentation page in a separate window, but it seems to be gone from Xcode 4.

Answer (score 0):

No exact answer, but you might consider using [AppKiDo](http://appkido.com/) as additional documentation browser.

Screenshot:

[image: AppKiDo]